# Unable to update rake (12.3.1, 12.3.0) to version 12.3.2 within Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, bundler, gem-bundler

I'm currently working on a Rails application within docker. When trying to install Rspec by running `docker-compose run web rails generate rspec:install` I get the following error.

```
Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I tried `docker-compose run web bundle update rake`

In my Gemfile.lock I see version `12.3.2` However when I run `docker-compose run we gem list` I see version `12.3.1`

I don't see to know where the issue is coming from. Since Gemfile and Gemfile.lock have the right version of bundler.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Loads environment variables from `.env`.


gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: %i[development test production]
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Interact with Box API via Boxr Ruby library.
gem 'boxr'
# PDF merger
gem 'combine_pdf', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.14'
# PDF parse into form
gem 'pdf-forms', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
# Add PNG, JPEG and Other images to PDF
gem 'prawn', '~> 2.1'
# Use httparty for requests
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.16.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running
  # in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.59.1', require: false
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8', '>= 3.8.2'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

Here is the Gemfile.lock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      actionview (= 5.2.2)
      activejob (= 5.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.2)
      actionview (= 5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
    activerecord (5.2.2)
      activemodel (= 5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      activerecord (= 5.2.2)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.6.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    archive-zip (0.11.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.2)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    boxr (1.4.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      hashie (~> 3.5)
      httpclient (~> 2.8)
      jwt (~> 1.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.13.2)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.0)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    cliver (0.3.2)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    combine_pdf (1.0.15)
      ruby-rc4 (>= 0.1.5)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.4)
    crass (1.0.4)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    dotenv (2.6.0)
    dotenv-rails (2.6.0)
      dotenv (= 2.6.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    ffi (1.10.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    hashie (3.6.0)
    httparty (0.16.3)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    httpclient (2.8.3)
    i18n (1.5.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jaro_winkler (1.5.2)
    jwt (1.5.6)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mime-types (3.2.2)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2018.0812)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.6)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.10.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    parallel (1.13.0)
    parser (2.6.0.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.0)
    pdf-core (0.7.0)
    pdf-forms (1.2.0)
      cliver (~> 0.3.2)
      safe_shell (>= 1.0.3, < 2.0)
    powerpack (0.1.2)
    prawn (2.2.2)
      pdf-core (~> 0.7.0)
      ttfunk (~> 1.5)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.6)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.2)
      actioncable (= 5.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      actionview (= 5.2.2)
      activejob (= 5.2.2)
      activemodel (= 5.2.2)
      activerecord (= 5.2.2)
      activestorage (= 5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.2)
      actionpack (= 5.2.2)
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.3.0)
    rspec-core (3.8.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.8.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.8.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-rails (3.8.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-support (3.8.0)
    rubocop (0.59.2)
      jaro_winkler (~> 1.5.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.5, != 2.5.1.1)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.10.0)
    ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.2)
    safe_shell (1.1.0)
    selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    ttfunk (1.5.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    unicode-display_width (1.4.1)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  boxr
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15, < 4.0)
  chromedriver-helper
  combine_pdf (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.14)
  dotenv-rails
  httparty (~> 0.16.2)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pdf-forms (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
  prawn (~> 2.1)
  pry-rails
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.0)
  rspec-rails (~> 3.8, >= 3.8.2)
  rubocop (~> 0.59.1)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.3p105

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```

Also, my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

# Bare minimum dependencies for our Rails App with the Apline image;
# build-base, git, nodejs, linux-headers, postgresql-dev, tzdata
#
# Project dependencies include;
# pdftk
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
  bash \
  build-base \
  git \
  nodejs \
  pdftk \
  postgresql-dev \
  tzdata \
  less

# Set the working directory for all commands after this
WORKDIR /app

# Bundle the application
# Copy our Gemfiles into the app directory and install
ADD ./rails_app/Gemfile \
    ./rails_app/Gemfile.lock \
    /app/

RUN bundle install
```

and my docker-compose .yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    image: onlineapps:0.0.1
    build: .
    # Remove the server.pid if it exists and then start the rails app on port 3000
    command: bash -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle install && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    # Mount our files to the app directory to detect changes
    volumes:
      - ./rails_app:/app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

if I run `docker-compose run web bundle install --deployment` I get the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/ext/msgpack
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190131-1-49a1tv.rb extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:227:in `expand_path': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:227:in `<module:MakeMakefile>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/msgpack-1.2.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing msgpack (1.2.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install msgpack -v '1.2.6' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  bootsnap was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
    msgpack
```

After installing `msgpack` it still doesn't update. Whats wrong?

Comment: Good news: Your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are not the issue.
I tried them in a container that I started with `docker run -it ruby:2.5-alpine  sh`

Comment: yes, I just runned `docker run -it ruby:2.5-alpine sh`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting all your files, makes it easier to help ;) I could not reproduce your problem, it fetched rake 12.3.2.

My suggestion:

```
docker stop <containers>
docker rm <containers>
docker rmi onlineapps:0.0.1
docker-compose run web bundle install --deployment
```

It fetched rake 12.3.2 every time I ran the above. I think there may have been a previous instance of the rake gem installed in your image. You could try fixing things with `bundle update`, but in the end the goal is to correctly build things from scratch.